# CSS flexbox proportionally set height of flex item when width below certain size

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm looking to create something like the following layout in CSS:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  box1: grow, min=height of content (variable)                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  box2: grow between 100px and 300px, when width below 900px,  |
|  proportionally shrink height. I.e. at |  600px, height       |
|  should be 200px etc.                                         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  box3: grow, min=height of content (variable)                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I have set up a CodePen here http://codepen.io/coxy/pen/LKeml?editors=110

It's using flexbox and it's almost doing what I need, I just can't figure out how to proportionally shrink the middle box when the width is below 900px.

Any suggestions you have would be great! It definitely doesn't have to use flexbox if there is a better way to achieve this...thanks!

Comment: does overflow + vw unit will help, beside , you need mediaquerie to set this in action below 900px width http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKfCt

Comment: Thanks! I think vw could be of some use here actually. In your link though, I need the middle box (red) to have a max-height of 300px. I've added the vw to my original example (http://codepen.io/coxy/full/cjoFm/) - think this is pretty close now... should be able to use media queries for the 900px restriction as you say. Thanks again.